# AWS Api Gateway custom authorizer polices with Path Params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to create a custom authorizer that returns policies allowing resources paths and its path params?

Example: 
Allow: GET /stores, GET /stores/{storeId}
Deny: GET /stores/{storeId}/products

I'm having problems with Path Parameters, because when I return a policy like arn:...:.../stage/GET/stores/{storeId}, API gateway blocks calls to GET /stores/123 or GET /stores/555123

Answer (score 0):

Such a policy is possible. You can return the following structure as custom Authorizer policy to achieve this:

```
{
  "principalId": "user",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1234567890:9f4xsv4jbl/prod/GET/stores"
      },
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1234567890:9f4xsv4jbl/*/GET/stores/{id}"
      },
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1234567890:9f4xsv4jbl/prod/GET/stores/*/products"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The {id} at the end of the second example won't work as desired unless you replace it with a specific id or allow all ids with "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1234567890:9f4xsv4jbl/*/GET/stores/*"

Comment: That is interesting. I tested with those statements. curl -H 'Authorization: a' https://9f4xsv4jbl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/stores -> works. curl -H 'Authorization: a' https://9f4xsv4jbl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/stores/123 -> user not authorized. curl -H 'Authorization: a' https://9f4xsv4jbl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/stores/123/products -> works. This would contradict that I need to specify the concrete id in the policy.

Comment: I don't think Api Gateway provides support for path variables.
I "solved" this for now by not using cache and every API call I Call my custom Authorizer wich returns an ALLOW | DENY arn..:v1..GET/stores/*